# Why this always save data even if those fields are empty?

Tags: php, cakephp

I have this model http://pastebin.com/tSaTvLxW and this is my Controller http://pastebin.com/iWeyvF71 and this is the associated view add.ctp http://pastebin.com/YWqwMtqx but when I add a new Information record and even if Education, Experience are empty always records are created in the respective tables and I don't know what cause that behaviour, can any help me to find this?

Comment: Browser Autocompletion Maybe? We need more details.

Comment: No, autocompletion is off and also the data for those fields goes empty, which details you need?

Answer (score 0):

When I run this, I see the following in the $this->request->data :

```
Array
(
    [Information] => Array
        (
            [name] => Test
            [lastname] => Name
            [email] => test@example.com
            [mobile_phone] => 1561561566
            [home_phone] => 1521521522
            [address] => 123 Any Street
            [other_information] => Other information
            [picture] => Array
                (
                    [name] => avatar.png
                    [type] => image/png
                    [tmp_name] => /tmp/php2Jvveh
                    [error] => 0
                    [size] => 89486
                )

        )

    [Education] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [education_content] => 
                )

        )

    [Experience] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [experience_content] => 
                )
        )
)
```

You will notice that the Education array and the Experience array, while empty, still exist in the `$this->request->data`. Because you are using the `$this->Information->saveAll($this->request->data)`, it will save an empty set of data to the table. If you do not want to save empty data, check the array to see if it is empty. If it is, unset it before you saveAll. The way you have your form setup, it would be something like this:

```
if (empty($this->request->data['Experience'][0]['experience_content'])) { 
    unset($this->request->data['Experience']);
}
if (empty($this->request->data['Education'][0]['education_content'])) { 
    unset($this->request->data['Education']);
}
$this->Information->create();
    if ($this->Information->saveAll($this->request->data)) {
    ...snip...
```